# Adding up values Before inserting into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

am trying to add the value of a column in database with the value that will collected from the an input box.

for example: i currently have 500 in a column and i want to add the 500 to a new value that is retrieved from a form (text box).

here is my code

```
<?php
     if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {  
$author = $_SESSION['user'];
//echo $author;
// check if posted is sent   

if (isset($_POST['input'])) {
if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['quantity'])) {
echo '<h4 class="alert_info">You Have Not Entered Any Value</h4>';
}      
else {
// retrievings foms data and declaring them as functions
$name = $_POST['name'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];  
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$category = $_POST['theItems'];    


// Allow apostrophe
$name2 = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$quantity2 = mysql_real_escape_string($quantity);
$amount2 = mysql_real_escape_string($amount);
$category2 =  mysql_real_escape_string($category);
// inserting the posts 
$insert = "REPLACE INTO drinks SET
name='".$name2."', quantity=' ".$quantity2." ', amount=' ".$amount2." ', category=' ".$category2." ', date=CURDATE()";
if (@mysql_query($insert)) {
echo '<h4 class="alert_info">Drinks added</h4>';
} else {
echo 'Error adding event: ' .
mysql_error() . '';
}
} }
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for something like this?

```
<?php
$val = $_POST['quantity'];
$query = "UPDATE drinks SET quantity= quantity + $val WHERE id={put current id here}";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
```

Comment: Since you're pulling quantity from $_POST, you must sanitize the input data - or some potential hacker could do some nasty stuff with your database...

A simple `$val = isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? intval( $_POST['quantity'] ) : 0;` will suffice... also check for $val === 0 so that you don't update if quantity is zero.

Comment: @Centril - Yes of course you should som valid checking! I was just illustrating the functionality though. If we're talking about security you shouldn't even use mysql_query().

Comment: I would also edit in to expain why `mysql_query` is deprecated, and it's proper replacements.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `SELECT` query to pull the current value from the column, add the value to the value you received from the text box, then `UPDATE` with the new value.

Comment: can i do that without a while loop??

Comment: Sure. Just get the value like normal from the database, store it in a variable then: `$totalVal = $pulledVal + $formVal;` and then insert the `$totalVal` into the database.

Comment: @Xenolithic Why select the current value and then update when you can do it in a single update query? bestprogrammerintheworld:s answer is better.

Comment: @Centril - Yes, I agree, and I gave him a +1 for it. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below:

```
update tableName set columnName = columnName+1
```